# AS3 removing dynamically created child movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip, removechild

I'm fairly new to AS3. Anyways, I'm try to remove a dynamically created child movieclip when clicked on. When a dirt block is clicked on, which is a child movieclip of 'world' I want to remove it.

I've tried various ways of removing it using removeChild. I've also tried moving the function inside/outside of the for loop that creates the movieclips.

```
var blockCount:Number = 0;
var blockArray:Array = [];

var world:MovieClip = new World();
world.x = 50;
world.y = 50;
world.name = "world";
addChild(world);

for(var i:Number=1;i<=100;i++){
    blockCount++;
    var tempGrassBlock:MovieClip = new GrassBlock();
    tempGrassBlock.x = i*16;
    tempGrassBlock.y = 256;
    tempGrassBlock.name = "b"+blockCount;
    world.addChild(tempGrassBlock);

    tempGrassBlock.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeBlock);
    function removeBlock(event:Event){
        world.removeChild(getChildByName(event.target.name));
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function removeBlock(event:Event){
    world.removeChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No function definition should be inside a for. I changed that in your code and rewrited a little below:

```
var blockCount:Number = 0;
var blockArray:Array = [];

var world:MovieClip = new World();
world.x = 50;
world.y = 50;
world.name = "world";
addChild(world);

for(var i:Number=1;i<=100;i++){
    blockCount++;
    var tempGrassBlock:MovieClip = new GrassBlock();
    tempGrassBlock.x = i*16;
    tempGrassBlock.y = 256;
    tempGrassBlock.name = "b"+blockCount;
    world.addChild(tempGrassBlock);

    tempGrassBlock.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeBlock);

}

function removeBlock(event:MouseEvent){
    trace("Is click really working? This target name is " + event.currentTarget.name);
    world.removeChild(event.currentTarget));
}
```